# Observable of Array to Array of Observables with ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular (9) App I get from WebsocketService an Observable of an Array of Objects like so:

```ts
public objects$: Observable<MyClass[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {

  this.objects$ = myWebsocketService.get()
```

Then I iterate over this with `*ngIf`and for every object call a component to render it:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let element of objects$ | async">
    <td><my-component [item]="element"></my-component><td>
```

That works. But that would mean, everytime objects$ changes every instance of my-component has to be reloaded. That seems very inefficient to me! Would be far better to a) only re-init the ones which actually changed and b) not even then re-init the my-components, but keep them, handle them observable out and subscribe to it. But I don't know how to formulate such behavior, in combination with the `*ngFor` - Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ever heard of trackBy with ngFor?

Comment: I had, but actually didn't realize that it's the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `trackBy` on ***ngFor** to deal with changes.
It allows you to check each element and rerenders only the ones that are new.
You can use an id or another unique elements to check them.

Template :

```js
<tr *ngFor="let element of objects$ | async; trackBy: trackByFunction">
</tr
```

Component :

```js
trackByFunction(index: number; element: MyClass) {
 return element.id; // or another unique property
}
```

Here is an example i made few days ago on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sample-performance-trackby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (with a message on new elements to tag them)

Comment: Thank you.. again oO

Answer (score 0):

It is an **observable** element. So you could **subscribe** to that object and Angular do check for changes and will update your variable without reloads.

Something like this:

```js
this.yourWebSocketService.yourObservableObject.subscribe( data=> {
    this.objects$ = data
}
```